# Proguard - exclude library

Tags: android, proguard

For testing purposes, I have some developer settings in my app. I include sometimes a view libraries and try what works best/fastest. I.e. image loader libraries like picasso/glide/ion...

I have a variable that says, which image loader to use. The user can't change that, so I would like following:

- I don't want to remove the library from my project (or comment the includes out and all classes), maybe tomorrow I have some new thing to test and I don't want to include the libraries again and write the extra code for it again
- I want my release build to exclude imported libraries completely, that are not used

I think this is possible via proguard, can someone show me how this would work, for example based on the 3 image libraries I posted? Or is this not possible with proguard?

**Edit**

I'm open to alternative solutions as well, for example something like c++ `#ifdef` or so (I think this is not possible in java though). Or some preprocessor solution, maybe via a plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

Define properties in your `build.gradle` for each image loading lib

```
project.ext {
   picassoEnabled = true
   glideEnabled   = false
   ...
}
```

Then in the buildType configuration you can selectively add additional rules that keep the relevant library:

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
    if (project.picassoEnabled) {
      proguardFile 'proguard-picasso.txt'
    }
    if (project.glideEnabled) {
      proguardFile 'proguard-glide.txt'
    }
  }
}
```

In each of the proguard configuration files for the libraries you will have rules to keep the library:

```
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.** { *; }
```

Now the important part would be to not reference each library explicitly from your application, but rather use reflection, so that ProGuard would by default remove all libraries (except for the one that is explicitly kept).

Comment: At first this looked quite good until I saw the reflection part... That's no option for me... But still, it's a solution. I would really like something like c++ style `#ifdef` to completely comment out code passages via a variable...